# Is there a way to enforce with ESLint that destructured objects are typed inline instead of with a separate type definition?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'd like to enforce that we always type our destructured objects inline rather than creating a separate type definition. For example, with a React component, I'd like to enforce that all our code uses this pattern:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ foo, bar }: { foo: string, bar: boolean }) => {
  return ...
}
```

rather than:

```
type Props = {
    foo: string, 
    bar: boolean,
};

const SomeComponent = ({ foo, bar }: Props} => {
  return ...
}
```

I looked through the ESLint rules and didn't find anything like this, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'd suggest you _don't_ do that. But assuming you've looked at e.g. https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ and not found what you want, you'll have to write your own rule or live without.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Outside of React `({a}: SomeType) => {}` is a _very_ common pattern. And this rule you want would force you to _not_ be able to reuse that type elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware - there is currently no existing lint rule that enforces this pattern.

You can enforce it with the [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) lint rule ([example](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.0.3&jsx=true&sourceType=module&code=PQKgUApgzgNglgOwC5gQewLQCdpK3AYyQgBMMoBPZAQwA8AuAAgG0xHGByCLLNLDgDRtGAb2HsoEGBCJ8mHegFtqSAgAtoACgBiAVwRE4aBABEZMalhVGEAxnoNIbAUVoAHHFCg27AQR5oAO4OhsauHtDexgCUjAB8jADyAEYAVjJIAAoqxFgIAHRultSKUPGMACoAyhUUbhC+COhI1sb5SHUNTWgtTsbl1bX1AEoQAGbcEAYQguKMipHUAOYQ8gCqkoyI8AgQjB31ZWN8jCS4WLpEujgkjJZLugvIULPsAL5gALpgIMBgYAc9pleG4ygBeUTCY5oJhQPCIJZCdjJSxMZJoNDSai2MBvADc-wIxjhjCqaAWAGFyW5jFMkABGRgQzQiRjQuworCMN5MYFoUGxMEJMTsHBIa4IRjAYCMfJy3GE4lIUnkiBUxQ03bIABMTMYLLZGI5lm5TFZ0Nh8IQiMYnLRGKxkreguFwjFEqlMrl+QV-2ljFG1CgxP2ajgZXDd1t1FucDO1EYGDZ1Bgmxp3icADdoGAiQgSWTKdTacgAMx6g3s6NcnkBiAx4wwCgAHnNGMt+Gtxqw9sx9adcRdkNFEHFeU9svlH2YbZhnEE1aYeF0ezen3yyjcmkrRurpsYfIFTOF3OieMYYCAA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)), however as the comments on your post suggest - this is not a good idea.

It is impossible to create a selector that solely matches on "react function components" because react function components are just functions. So (as shown in my example) such a simple approach will lead to a lot of noise and false positives across your codebase - which is BAD because it creates noise for your team.

You could achieve a lower amount of false-positives by instead [creating a custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules), however you will never truly be able to get that number to zero.

---

As an aside - this code style isn't great because it goes against industry conventions. It's very common and very popular to define a separate type so that it can be imported in consumers and composed together with other types - for example when creating higher-order or wrapping components.

By always defining the type inline you make that a lot harder as you have no choice but to go via `Params<typeof MyComponent>[0]` in order to get the prop types.